How can I use groupby in a way that each group is grouped with the previous overlapping group?
My DataFrame:
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'a': list('xxxxxxxxxxyyyyyyyyy'),
        'b': list('1111222333112233444')
    }
)

Expected output is a list of groups:
  a  b
0   x  1
1   x  1
2   x  1
3   x  1
4   x  2
5   x  2
6   x  2

    a  b
4   x  2
5   x  2
6   x  2
7   x  3
8   x  3
9   x  3

    a  b
10  y  1
11  y  1
12  y  2
13  y  2

    a  b
12  y  2
13  y  2
14  y  3
15  y  3

    a  b
14  y  3
15  y  3
16  y  4
17  y  4
18  y  4

Logic:
Grouping starts with df.groupby(['a', 'b']) and then after that I want to join each group with its previous one which gives me the expected output.
Maybe the initial grouping that I mentioned is not necessary.
Note that in the expected output a column cannot contain both x and y.
Honestly overlapping rows is not what I have used to do when using groupby. So I don't know how to try to do it. I tried df.b.diff() but It is not even close.

You can combine groupby, itertools.pairwise and concat:
from itertools import pairwise

out = [pd.concat([a[1], b[1]]) for a, b in pairwise(df.groupby(['a', 'b']))]

Functional variant:
from itertools import pairwise
from operator import itemgetter

out = list(map(pd.concat, pairwise(map(itemgetter(1), df.groupby(['a', 'b'])))))

Note that you might need to use sort=False in groupby if you want to keep the original order.
Output:
[   a  b
 0  x  1
 1  x  1
 2  x  1
 3  x  1
 4  x  2
 5  x  2
 6  x  2,
    a  b
 4  x  2
 5  x  2
 6  x  2
 7  x  3
 8  x  3
 9  x  3,
     a  b
 7   x  3
 8   x  3
 9   x  3
 10  y  1
 11  y  1,
     a  b
 10  y  1
 11  y  1
 12  y  2
 13  y  2,
     a  b
 12  y  2
 13  y  2
 14  y  3
 15  y  3,
     a  b
 14  y  3
 15  y  3
 16  y  4
 17  y  4
 18  y  4]

